# docker container on windows does not give any response

Tags: azure, docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-restful

Nice time of the day for everybody and Hello,
I am new at docker and I have faced a lot of problems with deploying of a Flask app.
My Dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM ubuntu:20.04

EXPOSE 5000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install pip requirements
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip unixodbc-dev python3-dev
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install flask-restful
RUN pip3 install werkzeug

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "127.0.0.1:5000", "main:app"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  tutorial:
    image: tutorial
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

main.py:

```
api.add_resource(Video,"/videos/<int:video_id>") 
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=5000,debug=False)
```

One if the main problems is that I cannot get a respose from container when it is locally runned on the local host.
In my docker log I see that `gunicorn` listening to a `port 5000`

```
[2020-10-09 14:20:19 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4

[2020-10-09 14:20:19 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (1)

[2020-10-09 14:20:19 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync

[2020-10-09 14:20:19 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
```

But according infromation from terminal I  see my container port opened.But it is not binded as it is specified in docker-compose file `ports:- 5000:5000.`

```
C:\Users\fele>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f3e0bfae76ec        containerregistr.azurecr.io/restvideoshop:1 "gunicorn --bind 127…"   5 hours ago         Up 33 seconds       5000/tcp            beautiful_chatterjee
```

Furthermore if I open my windows docker desktop and inspect my container I see one port opened in not binded state.
[image]

So when I run my test.py

```
import requests

BASE="http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
data=[{"name":"Duke Nuken","views":1000,"likes":10},
    {"name":"Never Again","views":20,"likes":80},
    {"name":"Belarus","views":500,"likes":70}]

for i in range(len(data)):
    response=requests.put(BASE+"videos/"+str(i),data[i])
    print(response.json())
```

I see folowing log in the terminal:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /videos/0 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x02FB8C30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer 
die Verbindung verweigerte'))
```

Can anybody give my advice and tell me why I cannot get a response from container? Should I do any other configuration in docker-compose file or set some additional code for gunicorn?One more question is not directly related to docker, I am planning to deploy container with Azure container instances so is it requiered to use inside of container a Nginx or Azure takes itself things to be done with Nginx?
Thanks in advance

Comment: why does yours `docker ps` shows hat both containers exited? status should be `Up`. Make sure that there are no errors when you start your application - you can do by doing it manually from inside of container.

Comment: @user2932688 Yes I was worng with docker log, but still I have a problem with not binded port, I thang the reason why it does not work depends on gunicorn. Beacuse it starts and works correctly as you can see in log of docker container. How can I start container manually from inside of container?

Comment: The two places you have `127.0.0.1`, change it to `0.0.0.0`.  If the process in a Docker container binds to 127.0.0.1 it will be unreachable from outside its own container.